# Calculate $x^4 + y^4 + z^4$ if $x + y + z = 1$ , $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 2$ and $x^3 + y^3 + z^3 = 3$

Tags: symmetric-polynomials

I saw this problem here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4FNCIYD8HdA.

Can anybody explain why I am getting different results using the following method.

Notations:

S(x<sup>4</sup>) = sum of all terms (each having coefficient 1) consisting of only one variable to the power 4 = x<sup>4</sup> + y<sup>4</sup> + z<sup>4</sup> = A

S(x<sup>3</sup>y) = sum of all terms (each having coefficient 1) consisting of 2 variables where one of them has power 3 and the other one has power 1 = x<sup>3</sup>y + x<sup>3</sup>z + y<sup>3</sup>x + y<sup>3</sup>z + ….  = B

Similarly,
S(x<sup>2</sup>y<sup>2</sup>) = C
and S(x<sup>2</sup>yz) = D

1<sup>4</sup> = (x + y + z)<sup>4</sup> = S(x<sup>4</sup>) + 4S(x<sup>3</sup>y) + 6S(x<sup>2</sup>y<sup>2</sup>) + 12S(x<sup>2</sup>yz) [you can use this website to verify if you have doubt: https://www.mathportal.org/calculators/polynomials-solvers/polynomials-expanding-calculator.php]

Or, 1 = A + 4B + 6C + 12D  …………………………………….(1)

2<sup>2</sup> = (x<sup>2</sup> + y<sup>2</sup> + z<sup>2</sup>)<sup>2</sup> = S(x<sup>4</sup>) + 2S(x<sup>2</sup>y<sup>2</sup>)

Or, 4 = A + 2C     ………………………………………………..(2)

3.1 = (x<sup>3</sup> + y<sup>3</sup> + z<sup>3</sup>)(x + y + z) = S(x<sup>4</sup>) + S(x<sup>3</sup>y)

Or, 3 = A + B   …………………………………………………...(3)

1<sup>2</sup>.2 = (x + y + z)<sup>2</sup>(x<sup>2</sup> + y<sup>2</sup> + z<sup>2</sup>) = S(x<sup>4</sup>) + S(x<sup>2</sup>y<sup>2</sup>) + 2S(x<sup>3</sup>y) + 2S(x<sup>2</sup>yz)

Or, 2 = A + C + 2B + 2D  ………………………………………..(4)

Eq(4) - Eq(3) gives

-1 = C + B + 2D ………………………………………………….(5)

Eq(1) - Eq(3) gives

-2 = 3B + 6C + 12D

Or, -⅔ = B + 2C + 4D …………………………………………….(6)

Eq(6) - Eq(5) gives

-⅔ + 1 = C + 2D

Or, ⅓ = C + 2D ……………………………………………………(7)

Eq(1) - Eq(2) gives

-3 = 4B + 4C + 12D

Or, -¾ = B + C + 3D ………………………………………………(8)

Eq(8) - Eq(7) gives

-¾ - ⅓ = B + D

Or, -13/12 = B + D

Or, -13/6 = 2B + 2D …………………………………………….(9)

Eq(4) - Eq(9) gives

2 + 13/6 = A + C      or, A + C = 25/6

Or, 25/3 = 2A + 2C ………………………………………………..(10)

Eq(10) - Eq(2) gives

A = 25/3 - 4 = 13/3

Ans is x4 + y4 + z4 = 13/3 . But in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4FNCIYD8HdA
They say the answer is 25/6. I didn’t understand nor want to understand how they reached that solution. All I want to know if my answer  13/3 is correct or wrong. If wrong then please explain why my method gives incorrect result.

I tried to solve by similar method for x5 + y5 + z5  and got different result from what is shown in the video.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Did you mean 
 $1^2.2 = (x + y + z)^2(x^2  + y^2  + z^2 ) = S(x^4) +\color{red}2 S(x^2 y^2 ) + 2S(x^3 y) + 2S(x^2 yz)$?

Answer (score 1):

You should have written

$1^2\cdot2 = (x + y + z)^2(x^2  + y^2  + z^2 ) = S(x^4) +\color{red}2 S(x^2 y^2 ) + 2S(x^3 y) + 2S(x^2 yz);$

with that, you should get the correct answer.

Comment: thanks, I just noticed that mistake

Answer (score 0):

We have in general if
$$
s_1:=x+y+z\textrm{, }s_2:=x^2+y^2+z^2\textrm{, }s_3:=x^3+y^3+z^3
$$
and
$$
s_4:=x^4+y^4+z^4
$$
and if 
$$
\sigma_1=x+y+z\textrm{, }\sigma_2=xy+yz+zx\textrm{, }\sigma_3=xyz\tag 1
$$
Then
$$
s_1=\sigma_1\textrm{, }s_2=\sigma_1^2-2\sigma_2\textrm{, }s_3=\sigma_1^3-3\sigma_1\sigma_2+3\sigma_3\textrm{, }s_4=\sigma_1^4-4\sigma_1^2\sigma_2+2\sigma_2^2+4\sigma_1 \sigma_3\tag 2
$$
Hence
$$
\sigma_1=s_1=1\textrm{, }\sigma_2=-1/2\textrm{, }\sigma_3=1/6
$$
Hence
$$
s_4=x^4+y^4+z^4=25/6
$$

Comment: $s_3=\sigma_1^3-3\sigma_1\sigma_2+3\sigma_3\implies 3=1+\dfrac32+3\sigma_3\implies\sigma_3=\dfrac1{\color{red}6}$

Comment: @J.W. Tanner. ok. I fix it. thank you very much