# Find value of $x^{5} + y^{5} + z^{5}$ given the values of $x + y + z$, $x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2}$ and $x^{3} + y^{3} + z^{3}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, systems-of-equations, symmetric-polynomials

If$$x+y+z=1$$
$$x^2+y^2+z^2=2$$
$$x^3+y^3+z^3=3$$
Then find the value of $$x^5+y^5+z^5$$

Is there any simple way to solve this problem ? I have tried all my tricks tried to multiply two equations , substitute $z=1-x-y$ , but things got messy nothing seems to work out .

Comment: I think you find this question [here](https://youtu.be/4FNCIYD8HdA), right?

Comment: Similar - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3601588/calculate-x4-y4-z4-if-x-y-z-1-x2-y2-z2-2-and-x3

Comment: I second the comment of @ProThala.  I found the youtube video to be very well presented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is yet another way, in case you are interested:
$$(x+y+z)^2=1\implies\sum x^2+2\sum xy=1\implies \sum xy=-\frac12$$
Therefore the polynomial equation whose roots are $x,y,z$ takes the form:
$$t^3-t^2-\frac12t+c=0$$
Summing this equation for each of the roots,
$$\sum x^3-\sum x^2-\frac12\sum x +3c=0$$
$$\implies3-2-\frac12(1)+3c=0\implies c =-\frac16$$
Multiplying the polynomial by $t$ and summing again,
$$\sum x^4-\sum x^3-\frac12\sum x^2-\frac16\sum x=0$$
$$\implies\sum x^4=3+\frac12(2)+\frac16(1)$$
$$\implies \sum x^4=\frac{25}{6}$$
Multiplying the polynomial by $t^2$ and summing again,
$$\sum x^5-\sum x^4-\frac12\sum x^3-\frac16\sum x^2=0$$
$$\implies\sum x^5=\frac{25}{6}+\frac12(3)+\frac16(2)=6$$

Comment: Thanks I knew that there is some unique way to solve this question and roots of polynomial Idea was on my mind but I couldn't put it together .

Comment: @RKK for some reason I find this method easier that using Newton's Identities, and I would certainly wish to avoid vast quantities of algebra involving symmetric functions etc.

Answer (score 7):

This form of equations can be solved systematically using [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities).

The problem at hand is a special case of $3$ variables. Let $e_1,e_2,e_3$ be the three elementary symmetric polynomial associated with $x,y,z$:
$$\begin{align}
e_1 &= x + y + z\\
e_2 &= xy+ yz + zx\\
e_3 &= xyz
\end{align}$$
This is equivalent to $\displaystyle\;(\lambda - x)(\lambda -y)(\lambda -z) = \lambda^3 - e_1\lambda^2 + e_2\lambda - e_3$.

For any integer $k > 0$, let $p_k = x^k + y^k + z^k$.
For 3 variables, the Newton's identities are:

$$\begin{align}
p_1 &= e_1\\
p_2 &= e_1 p_1 - 2 e_2\\
p_3 &= e_1 p_2 - e_2 p_1 + 3e_3\\
p_n &= e_1 p_{n-1} - e_2 p_{n-2} + e_3 p_{n-3} \quad\text{ for }\; n > 3
\end{align}$$

Given the known values of $(p_1,p_2,p_3) = (1,2,3)$, we have

$$\begin{align}
e_1 &= p_1 = 1;\\
e_2 &= -\frac12(p_2 - e_1p_1) = -\frac12\left(2 - 1^2\right) = -\frac12\\
e_3 &= \frac13(p_3 - e_1p_2 + e_2p_1) = \frac13\left(3 - 2 - \frac12\right) = \frac16
\end{align}$$

Substitute this into formula of $p_4$ and $p_5$, we have

$$\begin{align}
p_4 &= e_1 p_3 - e_2 p_2 + e_3 p_1 = 3 + \frac12\cdot 2 + \frac16\cdot 1 = \frac{25}{6}\\
p_5 &= e_1 p_4 - e_2 p_3 + e_3 p_2 = \frac{25}{6} + \frac12\cdot 3 + \frac16\cdot 2 = 6
\end{align}$$

The answer is $x^5 + y^5 + z^5 = 6$.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Multiply the third relation by the second so that you obtain
\begin{align*}
(x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2})(x^{3} + y^{3} + z^{3}) & = x^{5} + y^{5} + z^{5} + x^{2}(y^{3} + z^{3}) + y^{2}(x^{3} + z^{3}) + z^{2}(x^{3} + y^{3})
\end{align*}

Now we can rearrange the last expression as
\begin{align*}
x^{2}y^{2}(x + y) + x^{2}z^{2}(x + z) + y^{2}z^{2}(y + z) & = x^{2}y^{2} + x^{2}z^{2} + y^{2}z^{2} - x^{2}y^{2}z - x^{2}yz^{2} - xy^{2}z^{2}\\\\
& = x^{2}y^{2} + x^{2}z^{2} + y^{2}z^{2} - xyz(xy + xz + yz)
\end{align*}

Hence the problem has been reduced to study the last relation.

Before keep going, notice that
\begin{align*}
x^{2}y^{2} + x^{2}z^{2} + y^{2}z^{2} & = (xy + xz + yz)^{2} - 2xyz(x + y + z)\\\\
& = (xy + xz + yz)^{2} -2xyz
\end{align*}

In order to find the remaining expression, let us observe that
\begin{align*}
(x + y + z)^{2} = x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2} + 2(xy + xz + yz) \Rightarrow xy + xz + yz = -\frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}

At last but not least, we have to find the value of $xyz$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: How will we find value of $\sum x^2y^2$

Comment: I have edited my answer. It depends on the values of $xy + xz + yz$ and $xyz$.

Answer (score 0):

Another way.

Let $x+y+z=3u$, $xy+xz+yz=3v^2$,where $v^2$ can be negative,  and $xyz=w^3$.

Thus, $u=\frac{1}{3}$ and since
$$2=x^2+y^2+z^2=9u^2-6v^2,$$
we obtain $$v^2=-\frac{1}{6}.$$
Also, since $$3=x^3+y^3+z^3=27u^3-27uv^2+3w^3=1+\frac{3}{2}+3w^3,$$ we get $$w^3=\frac{1}{6}.$$
Id est, $$x^5+y^5+z^5=243u^5-405u^3v^2+135uv^4+45u^2w^3-15v^2w^3=6.$$
I used the following identities, which easy to prove and which we always use in the $uvw$'s method.

About $uvw$ see here https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h278791

$$x^2+y^2+z^2=9u^2-6v^2,$$
$$x^3+y^3+z^3=27u^3-27uv^2+3w^3$$ and
$$x^5+y^5+z^5=243u^5-405u^3v^2+135uv^4+45u^2w^3-15v^2w^3.$$
There are also:
$$\sum_{cyc}(x^2y+x^2z)=9uv^2-3w^3,$$
$$\sum_{cyc}x^2y^2=9v^4-6uw^3$$ and more

Comment: Do you use some identities that are missing from the answer?

Comment: @user26857 I added something for you... I think, it's much more better than to use  elementary symmetric polynomials  because we obtain a homogeneous symmetric polynomial and for $x=y=z$ we get the same value. This writing useful for inequalities proof, where usually (not always, of course)  equality occurs for $x=y=z$. If we'll use elementary symmetric polynomials so we'll miss a homogeneity.